# Sharepoint 2010 Conditional XSL Style based on field values?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, xslt

I am working on a Sharepoint 2010 site. I have a content query webpart with a custom itemstyle template. The items pulled in via the query have a few custom columns (multiline text, image, singleline text). I want to be able to render the fields differently depending on what information has been added. So the multiline field value and the image value should display in the same section of the html but only one of them will render depending on which field has been filled. Can you have two field values in between the same div tag and only render if a user entered something in one field? Is there a way to include conditional logic to determine how to display the results of a query in the xsl. I am open to alternative suggestions on how this could be achieved.